# Depth first search in finding a path in matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, traversal, depth-first-search

My understanding about dfs is using stack (bfs using queue). However, if i want to traversal a matrix in dfs. How do I suppose to do that?

Suppose I have a matrix and I want to find a path start from top left to bottom right, and it can only move down and right.

```
 public void dfsHelper(int[][] matrix, int i, int j ){                
    if (i >= row || j >= col) return;
    if (i == row - 1 && j == col - 1) {
        return;
    }
    dfsHelper(matrix, min, i, j + 1);
    dfsHelper(matrix, min, i + 1, j);
  }
}
```

Above is an online version a dfs on a matrix, I can only see it as a recursion, why it is a dfs?

Comment: Why do you think it's not a DFS? To put it another way, which invocation do you think will happen first - `dfsHelper(matrix, 0, col)` or `dfsHelper(matrix, 1, 0)`?

Comment: I see that as an example of recursion. It is not a search for anything, since it doesn't actually *do* anything, however recursion is a stack (call stack to be exact), so by the very nature is Depth-First.

Comment: Oh, OK, well call it a [depth-first *traversal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_traversal) then if that is all that you are hung up on (the wikipedia page even redirects to "depth-first search"). That you aren't searching for anything in particular is not very important.

Comment: It is depth-first because it will traverse to the full depth of `j`-axis before it traverses `i`-axis.

Comment: I've never implemented DFS in a graph with an adjacent matrix representation, but the idea of the DFS algorithm is the same: you go as much in depth as possible first, and only then you explore the rest. In a matrix representation `A[i][j]` is 1 if there's a connection from node `i` to node `j`. Of course you need to start from a node and then go all the way down until you find a node that has already been visited. Do this recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth First Search is an algorithm mainly used for tree or graph traversal. What makes an algorithm a Depth First Search is that it searches all the way down a branch before backtracking up.

The algorithm you posted first looks at the current element, then recursively calls itself on the right and down children. The algorithm will fully explore the right branch (in this case i,j+1) before backtracking up to run on the down branch (i + 1, j).

If you are still confused about DFS I would first try reading the [Depth-First Search Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to get a better understanding of what the algorithm is all about

Comment: j+1 is right and i+1 is down? what is left and right?

Comment: left and right was just an analogy to working with a binary tree like structure, sorry if that was confusing, i will edit the answer accordingly. The main idea though is that it walks down the children branches fully, whatever they may be called, before moving onto the next branch

Comment: so if i switch the order of visiting down and right, it still the dfs, right? Just vist the down first this time.

Comment: Yup, the order in which you visit does not change whether or not it is a dfs. If you are interested in some more information about ordering, check out this wikipedia article (specifically the depth first search section) on [Tree Traversals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search) that has a good explanation of what the ordering types are, with pictures to help

Answer (score 4):

It may be easier to look a small (3x3) matrix as an example :

```
  00 01 02
  10 11 12
  20 21 22
```

Because you start at (0,0) and can step only "right" and "down" ,while doing dfs, the following tree walk appears:

```
         00
      /   | 
     01   10
     |    |  \
     02   11  20
          |    |
          12   22
```

Answer (score 1):

`DFS` and `BFS` are two methods of traversing a graph or matrix as you say.

Now coming onto your question. You are using a `recursive` function (Same thing that a `stack` internally does), `DFS` is nothing but traversing deeper and deeper before backtracking up while maintaining the visited vertex array in case of any cycles. Your method does exactly the same.

`Recursive` implementation of DFS

```
1  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v as discovered
3      for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if vertex w is not labeled as discovered then
5              recursively call DFS(G,w)
```

`Iterative` implementation

```
1  procedure DFS-iterative(G,v):
2      let S be a stack
3      S.push(v)
4      while S is not empty
5            v = S.pop()
6            if v is not labeled as discovered:
7                label v as discovered
8                for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
9                    S.push(w)
```

Pseudocode source is Wikipedia [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: You should at least mention that you took this code from Wikipedia, IMO.

Comment: Done. Thanks for mentioning. I forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Depth-first search (`DFS`) and breadth-first search (`BFS`) are two different styles of traversing through graphs. Depth-first traverses down a singular path of children nodes until it reaches the final node of a particular branch or path. Breadth-first traverses by examining all nodes of a certain depth from the root node before traversing deeper through the graph.

Consider this example with 00 being the root node:

```
      00
  /   |   \
 01   11   21
 |    |    |
 02   12   22
 |    |    |
 03   13   23
```

Depth-first traversal order: 00, 01, 02, 03, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23

Breadth-first traversal order: 00, 01, 11, 21, 02, 12, 22, 03, 13, 23

You can use `iteration`, `recursion`, or both to implement a `DFS` or `BFS` algorithm, the only thing that determines whether you are using `DFS` or `BFS` is what order you are examining nodes in. `DFS` algorithms tend to lend themselves towards `recursion` due to the simplicity of the implementation, but `recursion` does not guarantee `DFS` and `DFS` does not guarantee `recursion`, that is an implementation detail.

Answer (score -4):

DFS and BFS are graph traversing algorithms and not used for traversing matrix. A graph can be represented in form of an Adjacency matrix and if an algorithm talks about traversing an adjacency matrix using DFS, it actually means that it is doing so for the graph or a tree that the matrix represents. [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) is an example in Java.

Comment: Your first line contradicts your rest three lines